# Error parsing datetime string "09-11-2017 00:02:00" at position 8

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime

I created a data frame with a column of datetime objects, re sampled it but would now like to turn the data frame into a list of lists - where the datetimes are now strings again.

```
for i in range(1, len(dataf.index)):
    dataf["Time Stamp"][i] = datetime.strftime(dataf["Time Stamp"][i], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print(dataf["Time Stamp"][i])
```

I keep getting the error 
(note the print part is just for me to check the output)

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "09-11-2017 00:02:00" at position 8
```

But from what I can tell my date format is exactly the same. I've even tried different capitalization in '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S' to no avail.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to

```
dataf['Time Stamp'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

So to rewrite the column

```
dataf['Time Stamp'] = dataf['Time Stamp'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

If you have errors, it's probably because the column isn't actually datetime.

```
dataf['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(
    dataf['Time Stamp']
).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

If you have non-parsable data

```
dataf['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(
    dataf['Time Stamp'], errors='coerce'
).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```